# DB stuck at 1000 for new id #'s

Tags: sql, database

HI I have a site that adds new users to a data base and assigns an id number.

We just hit the 1000 mark and now all new entries are stuck at XXX1000

I think this is where the issue is

```
sub getpilotid
    sql = "Select * From Pilots Order by PilotID ASC"
    set rs = con.execute(sql)
    if not rs.eof then
        rs.movelast
        idtemp = Right(rs("PilotID"), 3)
        newid = cint(idtemp) + 1
        if len(newid) = 1 then
            newid = "00" & newid
        elseif len(newid) = 2 then
            newid = "0" & newid
        end if
        pilotid = "ANW" & newid
    end if
    rs.close
    set rs = nothing
end sub
```

I think it needs a line added for now (1) leading but have no clue.
Any help would be appreciated.

thanks 
Andrew

Comment: What type of database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this code was designed to work with integer IDs that are stored as strings in the database, prepended with the string 'ANW'.

Padding with zeroes is used to make IDs less than 100 still take up three characters in the string. Eg the integer 5 will become "005", and the integer 71 will become "071". (See below for more detail.)

Here we take the last three characters of the "PilotID" field, eg "052"

```
idtemp = Right(rs("PilotID"), 3)
```

Here we convert the string to an integer, eg newid = cint("052") + 1

```
newid = cint(idtemp) + 1
```

For our example, newid now has an integer value of 53

The following code pads the front of the string with zeroes, if need be, so it will be at least 3 characters long. It has a side effect of converting single and double-digit integers into a three-character string.

```
if len(newid) = 1 
then 
   newid = "00" & newid 
elseif len(newid) = 2 
then 
   newid = "0" & newid 
end
```

So newid is converted from the integer 52 to the string "052". If it had been a three or four digit number, such as 1000, it would not have been converted to a zero-padded string.

```
pilotid = "ANW" & newid
```

pilotid now equals "ANW052".

If the previous id was "ANW1000", I'd expect the first line of code I quoted to take the last three digits -- making idtemp equal to "000".

I'd expect pilotid to start over at "ANW001". But it's instead set to "ANW1000". And here is the culprit. It's also probably the reason why zero padding was used for the string version of the IDs:

```
sql = "Select * From Pilots Order by PilotID ASC"
```

"ANW999" will appear first, ahead of all other strings including "ANW1000". Which means "999" keeps being used as the base from which to calculate the next id.

Comment: Nice explanation.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 1):

The counter generator assumes that there would not be more than three digits.  To fix it:

1) All the existing entries must have more digits, but that could well break links to those records.

2) The code to create the digits needs to handle string lengths of 3, 4, 5, ... up to the new maximum.

---

Note that this is not a very good way to handle IDs.  They should be integers and if any use needs leading zeros, format them as such when needed.

Comment: Ok thank you for those clarifications.This was built many years ago and those that did it are no longer around, so I am the one having to handle it.  If I add another number to all the id's and change all the records numbers as well to match, this should work? and would I change the number (3) in     idtemp = Right(rs("PilotID"), 3)    to (4)  that would allow use through 9999?

Comment: @AndrewCook:  It should but there is the pesky work *all*.  If there is some external database, an automated spreadsheet, a webform, or any other data references to the 3 digit IDs, *all* means you'll have to hunt them all down and adapt them.  Good luck!

Comment: thank you but do I need to change the (3) to a (4) and add another line for leading 000?